# accidently deleted /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl, undelete

I accidently deleted `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` folder. Now I am unable to neither install nor update youtube-dl.

How do I fix it or undo it ?

**I tried :**

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2016.02.05.1/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Now the `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` folder has come back but i am unable to download any videos using youtube-dl.

Comment: what happens if you type `youtube-dl --help` in the terminal?

Comment: @incBrain nothing happens. shows nothing

Comment: so there is no output at all?

Comment: @incBrain yes..

Comment: @incBrain same happens when i try to download using youtube-dl....no output

Comment: so it doesn't matter which program are you running from the terminal you never see some output? Do you have python installed?

Comment: @incBrain other programs seems to work fine... `python -V` is `Python 2.7.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

`sudo mkdir -v -p /usr/local/bin`

`sudo curl https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2016.02.05.1/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`

`sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`

Comment: thanx. ohh that fixed it i guess.